# Is there a way to have incremental IDs (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4) when adding rows on ng-grid and firebase/angularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ng-grid, angularfire

When I seed some data to my ng-grid & firebase like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngGrid']);
var fb = new Firebase('https://mybase.firebaseio-demo.com/');

fb.set([
    {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
    {name: "Enos", age: 34}
]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($firebase, $scope, orderByPriorityFilter) {
    $scope.data = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.$watchCollection('data', function() {
       $scope.myData = orderByPriorityFilter($scope.data); 
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

And then when I let users/try to add a new row which they themselves can populate and use this:

```
$scope.addRow = function () {
     $scope.myData.push({name: ' ', age: ' '});
     $scope.data.$add({name: ' ', age: ' '});

}
```

`addRow()` sits on `ng-click="addRow()"`

Now the problem is `fb.set({})` method adds data using incremental numeric keys (as in 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc) but `addRow()` methods adds data on top of `fb.set({})`, but using firebase keys like "htGDHfdgRWS".

Is there a way to have incremental IDs when adding rows? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental numeric IDs are tricky in a distributed context, since there are multiple clients trying to edit the data at the same time. Instead, Firebase offers a more powerful primitive via the `push` method (or, in AngularFire, the `$add` method). These IDs are chronologically incremental by default and won't clash with other clients who may be trying to write to the same location.

I'd strongly consider a way to utilize these auto-generated IDs and then mapping them back to the grid as appropriate.